# Cannot save or load Integer with Preferences

Tags: android, preferences, libgdx, sd-card

So I have constructed a class `SaveAndLoad` that looks like this:

```
public class SaveAndLoad {
    public Preferences pref;
    public final String path = "Highscore";

    public SaveAndLoad() {
        pref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Gametitle");
    }

    public void saveInt(int value) {
        pref.putInteger(path, value);
        pref.flush();
    }

    public int getInt() {
        return pref.getInteger(path);
    }
}
```

When I try to save my highscore I call `saveInt(highscore)` and when you turn the game on again I call `getInt`.

```
    constructor(){
        SaveAndLoad sdRemote = new SaveAndLoad ();
        try {
            highscore = sdRemote.getInt();
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            highscore = 0;
      }
    }
```

The problem is that when I start the game again after a earlier game, the highscore don't load, it returns zero...

I've done the manifest permission:

Thanks
///Daniel

Ps. In the last answer I say it works on some devices, but I found out later that was not the case.

Comment: Should that be `highsccore = getInt();` ???

Comment: Couple of things, where/what is the code for when you call saveInt() and where do you construct your SaveAndLoad class? Do you call saveInt() anywhere? Are you sure it is being called? Do you construct a SaveAndLoad instance every time you access the preferences? Too many unknowns for me to really understand why it isn't working. I haven't encountered this problem before.

Comment: I do like it should be done, I create aa SaveAndLoad class in my gamescreen constructor and call saveInt when you die and the highscore is higher then before.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you retrieve data like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int silent = settings.getInt("score", 0);
```

And save it like this:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("score", playerScore);
  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit(); //<----------
```

Edit:

Ah you are using GDX. In that case make sure you are initializing this class after GDX has initialized. Check if `Gdx.app.getPreferences("Game");` is returning null.

Edit2:

Ok, so we have confirmed it's a problem with Gdx on certain devices (that sucks).

If you REALLY need to make this work on both Desktop and Android devices there is another way. If you just want your game to work on Android you just should't use Gdx at all for saving the data.

I suggest you use something called a GDX Android interface. This way you can handle saving data on Android devices yourself using native Android calls that I used in this answer. This isn't really easy though but there is a tutorial here:

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Comment: OP uses a Gdx framework, while this will work, I think the quesetion is specifically about this framework

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gdx.app.getPreferences("Game"); is not returning null!

Comment: I think Gdx might be buggy on some devices. Did you try testing this on a desktop version of your game? Does it work there? Your code should work fine.

Comment: before i tried with my galaxy tab 2 and it didn't work. When I now tried my samsung galaxy phone it seemed to work fine.. But I don't want it to work sometimes..

Comment: Gonna check it out! Thank for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

you can **store** and **retrive** *data* from this.

following code of **class** and **methods**.

```
public class SaveAndLoad {
        public SharedPreferences pref;
        public final String path = "Highscore";

        public SaveAndLoad() {
            pref = Gdx.app.getSharedPreferences("Gametitle",MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        public void saveInt(int value) {
        Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putInt(path, value);
            edit.commit();
        }

        public int getInt() {
            return pref.getInt(path,0);
        }
}
```

for **Save HighScore**.

```
int highscore = 0;
SaveAndLoad sdRemote = new SaveAndLoad ();
        try {
        highscore = sdRemote.getInt();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

for **get HighScore**.

```
int highscore = 255;
SaveAndLoad sdRemote = new SaveAndLoad ();
        try {
        sdRemote.saveInt(highscore);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this code *working properly* for me. and use this i'm sure its *useful for you*.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you are doing everything correctly, which leaves the option of us testing the device in question. If you could run the following application listener on the device and see if MyValue is increasing each time you run the application on the device.

```
public class PrefTest implements ApplicationListener {
    @Override public void create() {
        final Preferences pref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("TestApp");
        int value = pref.getInteger("MyValue", 0);
        Gdx.app.log("MyValue", Integer.toString(value));
        value++;
        pref.putInteger("MyValue", value);
        pref.flush();
    }

    @Override public void render() {}

    @Override public void dispose() {}

    @Override public void resize(final int width, final int height) {}

    @Override public void pause() {}

    @Override public void resume() {}
}
```

You should see value increase in the LogCat each time you launch the application. Example, install app and run, back out and launch from the icon, repeat the back out and launch. If this works, then we know the issue is something to do with your code. If this doesn't work, then we know the issue is something with LibGDX or the phone itself.